# Is there an algorithm better than O(N²) to determine if matrix is symmetric?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic, big-o

### Algorithm requirements

Input is an arbitrary square matrix `M` of size `N×N`, which *just* fits in memory.

The algorithm's output must be `true` if `M[i,j] = M[j,i]` for all `j≠i`, `false` otherwise.

### Obvious solutions

1. **Check if the transpose equals the matrix itself (`M`<sup>T</sup>`=M`)**. Easiest to program in many environments, but (usually) consumes twice the memory and requires `N²` comparisons worst case. Therefore, this is O(`N²`) and has high peak memory.
2. **Check if the lower triangular part equals the upper triangular part**. Of course, the algorithm returns on the first inequality found. This would make the worst case (worst case being, the matrix is indeed symmetric) require `N²/2 - N` comparisons, since the diagonal does not need to be checked. So although it is better than option 1, this is still O(`N²`).

### Question

Although it's hard to see how it would be possible (the `N²` elements will all have to be compared somehow), is there an algorithm doing this check that is better than O(`N²`)?

Or, provided there is a proof of non-existence of such an algorithm: how to implement this most efficiently for a multi-core CPU (Intel or AMD) taking into account things like cache-friendliness, optimal branch prediction, other compiler-specific specializations, etc.?

This question stems mostly from academic interest, although I imagine a practical use could be to determine what solver to use if the matrix describes a linear system `AX=b`...

Comment: Can you have a sparse matrix representation?

Comment: @Leeor: yes, full or sparse should both be supported

Comment: I'm just saying that with sparse graphs you may get better complexity if the number of elements is significantly lower than n^2

Comment: Sorry in advance because what I am going to say might be very stupid. But the O(N^2) here is confusing me. If you have a matrix M of size S where s=nxn, and your algorithm is performing S number of comparisons, isn't that O(n) ?

Comment: @Pedrom that would be O(S), not O(n), and O(S) is O(n^2).

Comment: @AshutoshGupta It seems very odd to me to state data structure in terms of the square root of its number of elements. Also, it doesn't make sense to me to analyze the algorithm in terms of N if the structure has Nˆ2 elements. The algorithm is linear because it would check every element just once. Saying that is O(nˆ2) is misleading at best

Comment: @Pedrom totally agree to that as a choice of correct input size.  It is a topic to be thought about in 'Algoithms' perspective.  Although, the underlying complexity doesn't change since one has to make S or n^2 comparisons to achieve their output. For example if one is dealing with k matrices, and each matrix is seen as 1 input, will the algorithm become O(1) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a dense matrix, the answer is a definite "no", because any uninspected (non-diagonal) elements could be different from their transposed counterparts.

For standard representations of a sparse matrix, the same reasoning indicates that you can't generally do better than the input size.

However, the same reasoning doesn't apply to *arbitrary* matrix representations.  For example, you could store sparse representations of the symmetric and antisymmetric components of your matrix, which can easily be checked for symmetry in O(1) time by checking if antisymmetric element has any components at all...

Answer (score 10):

Since you will have to examine all the elements except the diagonal, the complexity IMO can't be better than O (n^2).

Comment: That's what I think too, but that's also what I thought the first time I thought about sorting :) I was hoping some similar "smart tricks" can be used for this...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis For a matrix O(n^2) is equivalent to linear in no. of elements because there are N^2 elements. I can't see how you can do better than this.

Comment: I know, but if there's anything I've learned about algorithms, it's that "I can't see how..." is not an argument in favor of "it does not exist.".

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis To get a correct output you must know some property of each of input so as u have not given an property of input matrix hence you will atleast have to check all the elements of matrix. Some people argue when they say binary search is O(logn) which is less than reading each value once but there is an important property given that array is sorted which tells us that each element has a number less than it before it and more than it after it. That is enough info needed about each element for binary search.

Comment: The complexity can't be less than N^2 because N^2 - N values have to be read. End of proof. Sorting doesn't help. There are N^2 elements so sorting them all using a comparison sort would take order (N^2*log(N^2) = O(N^2*logN) which is already larger than order(N^2).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can take a probabilistic approach here.

I think it's not a chance/coincidence that `x` randomly picked lower coordinate elements will match to their upper triangular counter part. The chance is *very high* that the matrix is indeed symmetric.

So instead of going through all the `½n² - n` elements you can check `p` random coordinates and tell if the matrix is symmetric with confidence:

```
p / (½n² - n)
```

you can then decide a threshold above which you *believe* that the matrix must be a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Interesting thought, this will certainly be sufficient in many contexts. OF course, not all :) When absolute certainty is required ("worst case"), it'll still have to be O(N²)

Comment: Yup. I tried writing latex style but it was not supporting preview. Thanks for the edit :)